# Create angular method containing two rest calls and the second depending on the result from the first

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I need to create a function that contains two separate rest calls, data is needed to be passed from the first call to the second. How should this be structured within angular.

This code is basically what I need it to do but I am not sure how to structure or format.

```
  getInfo(CName: string, PName: string, Id: string): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.FindService.getG(CName, PName)
        .subscribe((details: data) => {this.data = details})
    )
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.FindAdminService.getP(CName, PName, Id)
        .subscribe((details: Info) => {this.data = details})
    )
  }
```

Comment: What data should be passed to the second call? From your code example all information needed for the second call is already contained in the function parameters. 
The way to go would probably be to use rxjs `switchMap`operator or convert these observables to promises and then chain them together.

Comment: I need to extract the Id from the first request and pass it to the second...

Comment: can you also paste the "data" type, so I can see where the ID is coming from? This way I can provide a complete code sample for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do them at the same time :

```js
getInfo(CName: string, PName: string, Id: string): void {

  forkJoin({
    details: this.FindService.getG(CName, PName),
    adminDetails: this.FindAdminService.getP(CName, PName, Id)
  }).subscribe(({ details, adminDetails }) => {
    // Do what you need here
  })

}
```

If you have to chain one after the other :

```js
getInfo(CName: string, PName: string, Id: string): void {

  this.FindService.getG(CName, PName).pipe(
    switchMap(details => this.FindAdminService.getP(CName, PName, Id))
  ).subscribe(adminDetails => {
    // Do what you need here
  });
}
```

Comment: I need to extract the Id from the first request and pass it to the second..

Comment: @dconn then the second approach is for you. But from your code, it did not seem like it (the parameters for the second calls are NOT coming from the first call). You will find everything you need in the `details` variable of the second code snippet !